# Check if event is before, after or during other event

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

I'm stuck with a code. I want to see witch events from a MySQL database are before, after and during an inputted event.

I have a table with the following fields:

- `Event_id` (int AUTO_INCREMENT)
- `start_date` (date)
- `start_time` (varchar)
- `end_date` (date)
- `end_time` (varchar)

The start time and end time are in 24 hrs time format, and are stored without the colon separator `:` (so 23:50 will be stored as 2350, and 1:00 will be stored as 0100)

The dates and time of the inputted event will be in the same formats.

How can I make a query (or script) that get the event that is the closest to the inputted event, a query that check if there are events during the inputted event and a query that get the event closest after the inputted event?

Comment: Why are you not using the `TIME` or `DATETIME` formats?

Comment: why not just have 2 date & time columns for the start/end dates?

Comment: You should be storing your dates and times together using `TIMESTAMP` or `DATETIME`. In this case, `TIMESTAMP` seems like the best solution.

Comment: Ok, thanks. So if i use TIMESTAMP, how will the querys look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, start out by changing your scheme, so you instead have

```
event_id (int AUTO_INCREMENT),
start_date (timestamp), 
end_date (timestamp)
```

For your queries, you can now use `TIMEDIFF`.

**Closest event**

```sql
SELECT *, TIMEDIFF(input_date, start_date) diff
FROM events ORDER BY diff LIMIT 1
```

That will get you the next event.

**Events during event**

```sql
SELECT * FROM events
WHERE
  TIMEDIFF(input_date, start_date) > 0 AND
  TIMEDIFF(input_date, end_date) < 0
FROM events
```

That will give you events that are in progress.

You might need to wrap your `TIMEDIFF`s in `SECONDS()` before doing the comparison.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I only made a small adjustment to the closest event query.  SELECT *, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(input_date, start_date)) diff
FROM events WHERE TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('input_date', end_date)) > 0 ORDER BY diff LIMIT 1 Because otherwise you get also negative values (event is while or before event)

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you will indeed need to convert your DATE + VARCHAR fields to something more suitable such as DATETIME (i prefer datetime, its more readable when querying and as fast internally as timestamps)

Then after you have merged your 4 fields into 2 fields you can use two types of queries:

```
SELECT
    CASE 
        WHEN startDateTime <= "targetDate" AND endDateTime > "targetDate" THEN "while"
        WHEN startDateTime > "targetDate" THEN "before"
        WHEN endDateTime <= "targetDate" THEN "after"
    END AS timeframe,
    events.*
FROM
    events
```

Or you can use unions too, both will result in similar results, choose the one you prefer:

```
SELECT "before" AS timeframe, events.* FROM events
WHERE startDateTime > "targetDate"
UNION
SELECT "while" AS timeframe, events.* FROM events
WHERE startDateTime <= "targetDate" AND endDateTime > "targetDate"
UNION
SELECT "after" AS timeframe, events.* FROM events
WHERE endDateTime <= "targetDate"
```

PS: I haven't test it but the idea is right, you might have to adapt it.

Good luck

Comment: You shouldn't choose between DATETIME and TIMESTAMP depending on what _looks_ better. DATETIME is a very simple type that just stores a date as found in the calendar and a time as found on a clock, where TIMESTAMP stores a point in time. That is, timezones etc. are taken into account when it's stored. This is NOT the case for DATETIME - the two types have completely different applications! In this case, there's no excuse to use DATETIME.

Comment: Nice of you to demolish my post by saying that i shouldnt choose a time on what looks better. I guess it's a point of view, but i don't like working with TIMESTAMP for that simple reason, when i select data and make reports, i want to see my dates. About the TZ, you usually shouldnt store the TZ int he database and instead normalize everything to GMT+0 or UTC and then use the TZ of your user to adapt the output. Well, thats my point of view, there are millions of ways to get there.

Comment: I'm not demolishing anything, I'm giving critique. Regarding Time Zones, TIMESTAMP automatically converts everything to UTC for storage. Doing this manually seems redundant. You should format your reports in a view or elsewhere in your program. SQL data is not meant for direct presentation.

Comment: By the way, DATETIME isn't as fast as TIMESTAMP as you claim. They use twice the space and aren't internally cacheable.

Comment: I'm still trying to find out where you saw that DATETIME is slower than TIMESTAMP as i've always seens posts and tests on the web claiming that timestamps are slower than datetime also provided that they support less dates (can't go lower than 1970 with them), lookup timestamp vs datetime mysql performance on google, they all say that, one of many examples i found interresting: http://gpshumano.blogs.dri.pt/2009/07/06/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-vs-int-performance-and-benchmarking-with-myisam/

Comment: The example you post has query caching disabled. In most practical cases, it wouldn't be. Yes, TIMESTAMP has the obvious limitation of having to stay within the 1970-2038 bounds, but the queries asked about in this question makes it obvious that the dates are contemporary, thus that will not be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Closest before:

```
Select * from Event_table where start_date<=[imputed start_date] and start_time<[imputed start_time] order by start_date DESC, start_time DESC LIMIT 1
```

This sql gets the list of events before the imputed event, ordered by day descendent and by start time descendent to make the first result be the closest, and the LIMIT 1 only recovers 1 record, getting the closest before.

Maybe you prefer filter by end_date and end_time (instead of start_date and start time)to get the closest ending of an event.

To get the closest after change [imputed start_date] and [imputed start_time] to end_date and end_time and the '<' for '>'

To get the number of events during the imputed event use a simple query with between:

```
Select count(event_id) from event_table where ( start_date between ([imputed start_date] and [imputed end_date]) or end_date between ([imputed start_date] and [imputed end_date]) ) AND (start_time between ([imputed start_time] and [imputed end_time]) OR (end_time between ([imputed start_time] and [imputed end_time]))
```